Finding Jordan Normal Form of ridiculous matrix.
As an exercise for our exams we were tasked with finding the jordan normal form of the following matrix

where $\mathbb F_7$ denotes the finite field (modular arithemtic) over $\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$. I understand that over this field, certain operations like Gaussian Elimination are easier. Still, the amount of calculation seams infeasible.
What I have tried is looking at only the submatrix with the second row and column removed (since $3$ is obviously an eigenvalue). Since I was unable to calculate the characteristic polynomial with the usual method of $\det(A - \lambda I)$, I tried finding the kernel of each $A - \lambda I$ for all $\lambda \in \left\{0,\ldots,6\right\}$. To no surprise I failed once again due to the amount of calculation.
I am not asking for the solution, of course, but whether there is an obvious trick that I am missing. I would be grateful for any hints or suggestions.

A weird title : When is a matrix "ridiculous" ?

@Peter: the OP explains it clearly: the amount of calculation seems infeasible to do by hand. So is there a cleverer approach that makes it feasible? There is a sensible mathematical question here.

I guess this is a case of make some observations, try and milk everything out of them, and hope for the best. Here looking at the second column we see that $3$ is an eigenvalue. Unless I made a mistake $A-3I_6$ is a rank three matrix, and $(A-3I_6)^3=0$. You take it from there.
